# Object Class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I've got a simply question, in Java every class descendent directly or indirectly by Object class. Why? And what are advantage about this thing?

Best Regards

Comment: How else would you create an OO language? How would you write a method that accepted any type?

Answer (score 0):

In theoretical terms, the reason is that Java is an object-oriented language. Having everything that's an object be an `Object` is a reasonable starting point for an OO language.

In practical terms, it means we know that if we're dealing with a non-`null` object reference, it **will** have `equals`, `getClass`, `wait`, `notify`, and all the other useful methods from [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Comment: So we can consider a class that have methods that are essential for any java program. But according other people have a super class like object is not a good idea.

Comment: @WhatElse88: That's not an argument I'm familiar with. But in the 20 years since Java, OO thinking *has* moved on a fair bit, and in particular, inheritance (which used to be *supreme*) has been de-emphasized a fair bit in favor of composition. That said, though, I'm not seeing a strong argument against a base object type with *very basic* things on it (such as Java's).